# Filters match possibilities in Sylius Resource grid

Tags: grid, symfony, sylius

I have created a resource grid (auto-generated), and I would like to avoid having the 'matching possibilities' select displayed.
According to the [Sylius filters doc](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusGridBundle/filters.html), `"If you don't want display to user matching possibilites, you can choose one in a configuration. Then only the value input will display"`
I have done as explained, but I still have those select fields.
Here is an extract of my grid conf :

```
filters:
    customer:
        type: string
        options:
            type: contains
```

and for this filter, I still have the select field.

Any idea of the problem ?

Tks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked that it is a bug in the docs. Should be:

```
filters:
    customer:
        type: string
        form_options:
            type: contains
```

Comment: Tks CoderMaggie !

Comment: If I add the `form_options`, I loose the label on my text field. Any idea why, and how to get it back ?